# How to properly test and debug for apps that use camera flash?

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I made a very simple flashlight application. What's the recommended way to debug and test a flashlight app? I'm not sure because it uses the camera hardware flash, meaning that it's hard to just test via an emulator?

I tested through a device adb but I only have one Android device to test on.

Comment: Physical device. A simulator can make sure it doesn't crash, but that's about it.  (There's no reason a simulator couldn't have a little area that lights up if the flash is on, it just doesn't and it probably isn't a high priority feature request).

Comment: So the only way to really know if the app won't crash is to physically test them?

Answer (score 0):

I am a tester. 
How to test our apps
I use manual way. some software or websites helps me to test out applications. In your case I suggest

1. Make application layout in constraint/responsive.
2. check on minimum sdk devices.
3. Unit testing must means check all the functionalities of application.
4. No crash report.
5. check through wifi if internet app without internet also.
6. check on locking screen.
7. check on orientation.
8. id adb then please check on one device must.

I think this help you to improve your testing..